# How will two independent component talk to each other in angular2 js?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have two independent component navbar.ts and home.ts. I'm routing to home.ts component to when user logs in. I'm not been able to load the navbar.ts component in home.ts when i refresh the home page it's displaying the navbar.ts components. Here is the code.

## navbar.ts

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    template: template,
})

export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

    public isAuthenticated = new BehaviorSubject(false);

    constructor(private http: Http, public router: Router, 
                public loginService: LoginService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.loginService.isLoggedIn()) {
            this.isAuthenticated.next(true);
    }
 }
}
```

## home.ts

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: template,
    styles: [ styles ],
})


export class Home implements OnInit {

    constructor(public router: Router, public http: Http) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Comment: it's most likely that you put your service in ngOnInit,According to lifecycle hooks in angular2 it's gonna get executed only once while loading so you want to check your service and check its change, try ngDoCheck() {} instead, Use this method to detect a change that Angular overlooked. Give it a try and let me know, don't forget to implement DoCheck class.

Comment: Will i able to change the isAuthenticated variable in the home.ts. When i reload the page it's detecting the change of isAuthenticated. Otherwise it won't.

Comment: basically, ngOnInit() should be executed only once while loading and never look for any change so that's why when you reload it works but when you don't it's not working. that's my guess like it said most likely if you change to doCheck it gonna solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Majid it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's most likely that you put your service in ngOnInit, According to lifecycle hooks in angular2 it's gonna get executed only once while loading so you want to check your service and check its change, try ngDoCheck() {} instead, Use this method to detect a change that Angular overlooked.

DoCheck: Lifecycle hook that is called when Angular dirty checks a directive.

How to use:

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements DoCheck {
  ngDoCheck() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

[Document is here.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html)

so change your code to :

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    template: template,
})

export class NavbarComponent implements DoCheck {

    public isAuthenticated = new BehaviorSubject(false);

    constructor(private http: Http, public router: Router, 
                public loginService: LoginService) {}

    ngDoCheck() {
        if (this.loginService.isLoggedIn()) {
            this.isAuthenticated.next(true);
    }
 }
}
```

hope it helps.